# How can I put spaces in this

Tags: javascript

***The result below is coming out without any spaces***

```
let chars = "I'm The coolest title you'll ever meet!", i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) == 2 &&
        i != chars.length &&
        typeof chars[i] != "undefined" ?
        /**/null: document.title += chars.charAt(i++);
}, 120);
```

Comment: What do you mean by spaces? Do you mean the literal space character, or a duration?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the question what do you need ? How do you want that chars string to be converted to ?

Comment: Literal space char and I just want the document title to come out as  "I'm The coolest title you'll ever meet!"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `document.title += " "` gets trimmed away.

Do it like this and it will work:

```
let chars = "I'm The coolest title you'll ever meet!", i = 0;
let title = "";
setInterval(() => {
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) == 2 &&
        i != chars.length &&
        typeof chars[i] != "undefined" ?
        /**/null: title += chars.charAt(i++);
    document.title = title;
}, 120);
```

However this code can be improved by clearing the interval once the title is spelled out:

```
let chars = "I'm The coolest title you'll ever meet!", i = 0;
let title = "";
window.titleTimer = setInterval(() => {
    if (title.length === chars.length) {
        return clearInterval(window.titleTimer)
    } else if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) === 2) {
        return
    }

    title += chars[i++]
    document.title = title
}, 120);
```

Comment: Thanks @marco-a, I'm teaching myself JavaScript, and I just had heard of it 2 months ago, so I'm kinda a dumb dumb.